# I'm trying to get the text of the parents parents child div which I have to use for deleting it out of localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm new with programming so I get Learntasks like this one. For this task I had to create a flexbox which works like a table. I had to program a way to add and delete contacts to it.

Now I have to safe them in localStorage. So when I create a Contact it gets saved in localStorage but when I try to delete one it doesn't.

I tried doing it with

```
var fullname = $(".parentDiv:parentDiv:nth-child(1)").html();
```

But it just doesn't work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

```
          <div id="Row2">
            <div class="item">Haik Raf</div>
            <div class="item">26</div>
            <div class="item">01518384213</div>
            <div class="item">
                <button type="button" class="Mybutton">
                    X
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>




            $(".Mybutton").click(function () {
                // Removes its Row
                var abc = $(".parentDiv.parentDiv:nth-child(1)").html();

                window.alert(abc);
                localStorage.removeItem($(".parentDiv.parentDiv:nth-child(1)").text());
                localStorage.removeItem($(".parentDiv.parentDiv:nth-child(2)").text());
                localStorage.removeItem($(".parentDiv.parentDiv:nth-child(3)").text());

                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });
```

Output is "undefined" when I tried to display it with

```
windows.alert()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey after coming into work pretty calm i actually found an answer and i thought i'd post it here for anyone looking for a solve to a similiar problem.

using

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().eq(0).text();
```

Helped me so much the `eq(0)` pretty much tells which children i want to read out.

Good luck programming!